# Redux - action creators with params from different pieces of state

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, react-native-maps

I'm using React Native and Redux to create an app that helps users find nearby fast-foods. I've got two components : Map and Settings.

Each component is connected (via react-redux) to its respective piece of state. `Map` can also dispatch an action creator called `apiCall` :

**Map Component**

```
...
connect(
  ({ map }) => ({ map }),
  { apiCall }
)(Map)
```

**Settings Component**

```
...
connect(
  ({ settings }) => ({ settings })
)(Settings)
```

I would like the action creator `apiCall` to read values from both `map` and `settings` pieces of state : `this.props.apiCall(map, settings)`.

However, I want to avoid connecting my Map component to `state.settings` because it would re-render each time `state.settings` updates.

I'm still quite confused and have not found "the right approach" in solving this issue. These are the things I tried :

- Connecting `Map` to `state.settings` and using `shouldComponentUpdate()` to prevent useless re-renders
- Using `getState()` from the action creator to read `state.settings` value
- Encapsulating everything in another higher component and then passing down specific props

The first two worked but seemed a bit anti-pattern and the third one was still triggering re-renders. Not quite sure why even though it felt like a good solution. I have not tried selectors yet but it seems to be another alternative.

To sum up, my question is :

**How to dispatch an action that needs to read values from different pieces of state while avoiding unnecessary re-renders ?**

Comment: For what it's worth, I think comparing props in `shouldComponentUpdate` in order to prevent unintended rerenders is a good idea...

Comment: @MaxMillington is right. Also it might be worth looking into the [`reselect`](https://github.com/reactjs/reselect) library, it allows you to create memoized selectors so that your components connect update will only happen if some piece of data they are selecting from state changes

Comment: Thanks for your answers ! @AndrewG. I'll try reselect asap. From what I understand, selectors are meant to be used to compute derived data while keeping the state minimal. But from what you are saying, I could also use them to select and read the values I am interested in. I still have trouble understanding where it differs from a classic mapStateToProps. Is it because of "caching" and not needing to recalculate everytime a more specific piece of state ? Or maybe connecting to a single value instead of the whole piece of state ?

Comment: You're correct in that the main way it differs is the caching. I would need to refresh on exactly what it's doing but basically it caches the args provided to derive the state, and if those don't change it knows the it doesn't need to update your component. For my team we have found it is also nice even if you don't take advantage of the caching, because it allows you to share common logic used in your mapStateToProps

Answer (score 2):

You should use [`redux-thunk`](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk). That way you can return a function (a thunk) in your action creator, which will have access to state

```
const apiCall = (apiCallArgs) => {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
      let mapState = getState('map');
      let settingsState = getState('settings');

      return dispatch(yourApiAction);
    }
}
```